# Vimeo Javascript API retrieve view count

Tags: javascript, html, view, vimeo, vimeo-api

So I want to retrieve a video's viewcount via HTML and javascript and all Vimeo seems to provide is this, with no command documentation:

https://raw.github.com/vimeo/vimeo-api-examples/master/simple-api/simple/really-simple.html

So I have no idea what to do to retrieve a *single* video id and not the entire user's videos.

```
var url = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/' + vimeoUserName + '/videos.json?callback=' + callback;
```

And then once the JSON has retrieved the data, how to ask for the view count instead of the thumbnail and title. If I could find proper documentation it'd be easier, but they only seem to be generous towards those who want it in PHP. Anyone who has accomplished this and willing to help with this code example they provided?

Comment: Thanks MiJyn. For some reason no matter what I tried it wouldn't format that code line for me

Answer (score 5):

Documentation is here:

http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/simple

You want to make your AJAX request to:

http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/99999999.json

Where '99999999' is the numeric id for the video you care about.

This will given you an array with one object in it.

The property you want for view count  form the resulting object is 'stats_number_of_plays'.